# Nextjs API inaccessiable in production

Tags: amazon-s3, next.js, digital-ocean, aws-amplify

I am trying to host a NextJS app and everything seems to be working fine locally. I am able to get the data from the site and I can go to the site and see the raw json that is being returned, but when I try to get things working on production the API is completely inaccessible through the browser and through the Axios requests.

The server just returns `500` or `Internal Server Error`.

I have tried deploying on DigitalOcean App Platform and AWS Amplify, but both fail to connect to the API routes.

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-next-js-app-to-app-platform) for the NextJS SSR method that says to build and start using

```
// next.config.js

const path = require('path')
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack')

require('dotenv').config()


module.exports = {
    webpack: (config) => {
        config.plugins = config.plugins || []
        config.module.rules.push({
            test: /\.svg$/,
            use: ["@svgr/webpack"]
        });
        config.plugins = [
            ...config.plugins,

            // Read the .env file                                                       
            new Dotenv({
                path: path.join(__dirname, '.env'),
                systemvars: true
            })
        ]

        return config
    },
    sassOptions: {
        includePaths: [path.join(__dirname, 'styles')]
    }
}
```

```
// package.json
...
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "digitalocean": "next start -H 0.0.0.0 -p ${PORT:-8080}",
    "start": "next start"
  },
...
```

```
// api.js
const axios = require('axios')
const {getS3URL} = require('./aws')

require('dotenv').config()


export default async (req, res) => {
  const config = {
    bucket: 'bucket',
    key: 'folder/data.json'
  }

  const request = await axios.get(await getS3URL(config));

  try {
    res.status(200).json(JSON.stringify(request.data))
  } catch {
    res.status(500).json({ error: '500', response })
    res.status(400).json({ error: '400', response })
  }
}
```

```
// frontend.js
...
  const getData = async () => {
    console.log(`${host}api/daily-trip-stats`)
    const trips = await axios.get(`${host}api/daily-trip-stats`)
    const routes = await axios.get(`${host}api/daily-route-stats`)
    const stops = await axios.get(`${host}api/daily-stops-routes`)

    const cleanUp = async (data) => {
      return await data.map(fea => fea.properties)
    }
    return {
      routes: await cleanUp(routes.data.features),
      trips: await cleanUp(trips.data.features),
      stops: await cleanUp(stops.data.features)
    }
  };
...
```

Comment: Can you check the server logs when making the request to the API route in production? Also, you might want to include the `axios.get` call inside the `try`/`catch` block so it catches any potential errors thrown by it.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me that there are ways to debug remotely...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checked the server logs and found that the default region was not being set properly.

```
var { S3Client, GetObjectCommand, Config} = require('@aws-sdk/client-s3');
import { getSignedUrl } from "@aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner";

const getS3URL = async ({bucket, key}) => {
    const client = new S3Client({
      region: 'us-east-1' // !!! FORGOT TO SET THE DEFAULT REGION
    })
  
    var params = {
      Bucket: bucket,
      Key: key,
      Expires: 60,
      ContentType: 'blob'
    };
    const s3Data = new GetObjectCommand(params);
    const url = await getSignedUrl(client, s3Data, { expiresIn: 3600 });
    return url
  };

module.exports = {getS3URL}
```